# My mysqlworkbench is not responding in linuxmint?

Tags: mysql-workbench, linux-mint

My workbench is not responding in linuxmint even after connection? It says connecting and after sometime it says not responding force quit;

any solution for operating the workbench ? I want to work in workbench in linux as i could sucessfully run mysqlworkbench in windows?